# How to override object get fallback

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, properties, getter

I'm trying to create an object that returns the property name for any property that was accessed. Is this possible to do cleanly in javascript / nodejs? This is what I would like to accomplish:

```js
const mirror = {/*...*/};
console.log(mirror[1]);
// => 1
console.log(mirror.123);
// => '123'
console.log(mirror.randomPropertyHere);
// => 'randomPropertyHere'
```

I can overwrite a getter for a specific property, but I don't know how to do it generically. Also how can I differentiate between a number and a string?

My (not working) attempts

```js
const mirror = {
  get[1] () {
    console.log('number');
    return 1;
  },
  get['1'] () {
    console.log('string');
    return '1';
  }
};

console.log(mirror[1]);
console.log(mirror['1']);
```

Very much appreciate your time and help!

Comment: Since you already know the property you're getting, why do you need to know again? Seems redundant. Not to mention you can't have an Object property that's a number. That number will cast to a String.. and since the properties are the same only the last method will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a proxy.

```js
const mirror = new Proxy({}, {
  get(_, prop) { return prop; }
});
console.log(mirror[1]);
// => 1
console.log(mirror['123']);
// => '123'
console.log(mirror.randomPropertyHere);
// => 'randomPropertyHere'
```

> Also how can I differentiate between a number and a string?

Can't, object properties have to be strings or symbols.

Comment: Ah, this is a good start, thank you! Could I use a proxy of an array then to return numbers? I need one proxy for numbers and a different one for strings.

Comment: No. There is no difference between `arr[1] = 5` and `arr['1'] = 5`, since object properties have to be strings or symbols. Numbers in the code will get transformed to string properties automatically.